# Can't remove apple developer account in visual studio Mac

Tags: visual-studio-2019, macos-catalina, apple-developer-account

Hi I'm not able to remove apple developer account in visual studio Mac, remove button is disable and also on adding Apple ID it is not listing teams available.VS Mac Version 8.6.5, macOS 10.15.5; in which file is the information
stored about the id in VS Mac; an new installation of the ide is not a solution

Answer (score 9):

If VS prompts "An active membership to the Apple Developer Program is required to provision iOS devices for deployment. Learn More (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2117069)" when you are trying to add your Apple account, occurs that behaviour.

You can either remove the following file or edit it: `/Users/<YourUser>/Library/VisualStudio/8.6/DeveloperStorage8.6.json`

It is used by Visual Studio to store the accounts. but if prompts appears back, the result will be the same.

**Update**

It is still working with Visual Studio 2022 for Mac (Preview).

`/Users/<YourUser>/Library/VisualStudio/17.0/DeveloperStorage17.0.json`

Answer (score 0):

Click on Visual Studio (For Mac) menu > Preferences...

Locate "Publish/Deploy" section and find "Apple Developer Accounts" on list, like image below.

Add or remove accounts.

[image]